# How can I get lat on the boundary top of mapbox?

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox-gl-js

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mouse-position/ this gets latitude and longitude based on the mouse position but I want the latitude and longitude at the top bound of the map that is north from the center of the map.Is there an built-in method so I can access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method `getBounds()` that returns the boundaries of the map in the form the southwest and the northeast corners of the map (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api#lnglatbounds).

You've got the north latitude directly from what the northeast corner tells you. You can get the center longitude by averaging the two longitudes you get back. (Just beware of the special case, in the middle of the Pacific ocean, where longitude could wrap around the -180/180 line and get a little tricky.)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the results of `getBounds()` and `getCenter()` to get the north bound, and the longitude of the center:

```
var northCenter = mapboxgl.LngLat(map.getCenter().lng, map.getBounds().getNorth())
```